# Where the data is processed in api.ai, or in bot framework

Tags: bots, botframework, privacy, dialogflow-es

I'm using api.ai and facebook channel...my question is where the data is processed ...i want to know more about privacy of data...is processed inside of EU of outside ? Did you know where i can find this information ?

Comment: Why not [ask them](https://discuss.api.ai/)

Answer (score 2):

So through API.ai your user's utterances is parsed and handled through API.ai. If you have to select a region (for LUIS and/or hosting via Azure Bot Service, you must select a region for both services) then you're almost guaranteed beholden to the laws for that region.

After API.ai is done it sends a response to your chatbot, so you're processing (and responsible for) the data. But wait! Your chatbot sent the user's messages to API.ai itself, so even without API.ai you're responsible.

Now you're using a 3rd party (relative to the Bot Framework) channel, Facebook Messenger. Well they have their separate policies that you need to be aware of.

Who is responsible for, and what are the laws and regulations on privacy of data, are things you can look up. But as stuartd indicated, you should be asking this question directly on their forums or website.

[API.ai Terms of Use and Privacy Policy](https://api.ai/terms/)
 
[Only API.ai's Privacy Policy(?)](https://discuss.api.ai/privacy)
[Facebook Data Policies](https://www.facebook.com/full_data_use_policy)
 
*[FB Policy explained by 3rd party](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/facebook-messenger-privacy/)*
[Microsoft Privacy Statement](https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-us/privacystatement)
[Developer Code of Conduct](https://www.botframework.com/Content/Developer-Code-of-Conduct-for-Microsoft-Bot-Framework.htm)